# Reverse engineer C++ DLL

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, reverse-engineering

I have a small utility that was originally written in VS2005.

I need to make a small change, but the source code for one of the dlls has been lost somewhere.

Is there a free or reasonably priced tool to reverse engineer the dll back to C++ code.

Comment: Yes, Ghidra, an open-source decompiler originally produced by the NSA.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Hex-Rays decompiler](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/) is a great tool, but the code will be quite hard to read and you will have to spend a lot of time to reverse engineer the whole DLL.

Comment: Hex rays is probably the best but the code it will give you will only be usefull in figuring out how certain parts of it work and cant compile it. +1

Comment: If the change is small enough you can use the output of the decompiler to patch the dll in assembly use OllyDbg for instance.

Comment: Yes, OllyDbg was always my favorite to patch dlls, but only after SoftICE. How can anybody forget the legendary "SoftICe" ?

Comment: @abhilash Where to get Softice ?

Answer (score 7):

You might also want to have a look at ***OllyDbg*** which is a 32-bit assembler level analysing debugger. It is used to analyze binary code in scenarios where you do not have a source code. It is light weight debugger. ***OllyDbg*** is a shareware so you can download & use it for free..!!

Visit OllyDbg is home page [here](http://www.ollydbg.de/)

**PS:** Back in the day crackers used [SoftICE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoftICE) from NuMega for debugging into an executable & grab a snapshot at the values of registers. SoftICE was an advanced debugger. It was definitely the favorite tool for the crackers. I don't know about the present status of the product. NuMega's site had no information about it. I may have overlooked it but I could not find it. I recommend that you get your hands on a legacy version (4.0x) of SoftICE & apply the WindowsXP patch for SoftICE. Working with SoftICE is something of an "experience".

**Further Read:** [Reversing: Secrets of Reverse Engineering by *Eldad Eilam*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764574817)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the exact situation you have, and how much the functionality the DLL implements for your application. But I would argue that in most cases it would be better to rewrite the missing DLL based on the known functionality.

This is especially true if you have some documentation for it.

Trying to reverse engineer the binary code to assembler, then to C++ and then try to modify it to provide the existing functionality will be in most cases to time consuming, and maybe even impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Now you can use ghidra for free, or buying idapro

Comment: Link: https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra

Answer (score 1):

If your small change is to edit some text or to skip some routines, you could use a hex editor or a disassembler, but you won't be able to see the original C++ code, and even if you find a tool that turns the DLL back into code, all the variable names would be gone and it would be a big mess.

Answer (score 1):

A little depending on your situation I would keep the legacy/binary DLL as-is and write a wrapper DLL that will change and/or add any additional behavior.

The idea is to aggregate the old functionality in a new DLL which imports the old one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it like game and app crackers do: Use a disassembler and hack the Assembler code.